# What happens to Marla's tooth?

Tags: plot-explanation, i-care-a-lot

In the movie, ***I care a lot***, Marla Grayson is tortured and one tooth is punched loose as the result.

She takes that tooth out of her mouth and put it in a jug of chilled milk.

Then what happens to it? The tooth looks like a part of future plot and it is no-where to be seen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She visits the dentist that very same night and you see her in the dentist chair having the tooth re-inserted.  The scene is at about 1 hour 29 minutes into the runtime.

You see her looking at Fran in bed as she leaves, the time is 2:11 am on the bedside clock.  Then you see her waiting with the milk jug outside the dentist office and it is still dark.  Finally we see a few seconds of the tooth being re-inserted.

[image: Marla waiting outside dentist]

[image: Marla in dentist chair]

Apparently keeping a tooth in milk can help keep it 'alive' enough to be re-implanted in the mouth if the duration is quite short.

Comment: This is all so clearly shown, that I wonder if there is an alternative version skipping this scene in the netflix area you are in.

Comment: Or the whole thing is only about 1 minute long, so a brief distraction and you could easily miss it.